# how to change elements contained within custom adapter in list view in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have custom adapter using base adapter

now what I want is to change list item back ground image, color of text in text view, and backgroung image of image view.

these all elements are contained in raw layout of list view and I am inflating this raw layout in list view.

thanks...

Comment: I am sure there are a lot o tutorials on this, for example [tutorial](http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/#sthash.Y02hR76H.dpbs)

Answer (score 1):

Create instance for the listview like

```
ListView listview_variable = (ListView)findViewById(your id specified in xml);
listview_variable.setBackground(drawable image);
```

Place the background image that you want to show in res->drawable folder.